# How to make a custom jquery calender...............?

Tags: jquery

I have a text field in my webpage which shows a date. which also consist of a calendar icon beside the box.Now when i click the icon a calendar should popup under the text field. Then when i click on one date it should select a date when i select a second date the it should select a range and input the range into the text box.when i double click any one date then the that date only be selected.when a range is selected then the range on the calendar should be marked with a red line starting from 1st date and ends at 2nd date. How can I do this?

This is my text field:

```
Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerr" value="2016-08-26"></p>
 <img src="CalendarIcon.png" id="cal">
```

Comment: I suggest you try this [really helpful link](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=jquery+datepicker)

Comment: Doing so, could lead you to this [gold mine](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger)

Comment: I tried all of this

Comment: You clearly didn't try very hard. https://jsfiddle.net/p9fgz3zw/

Comment: I was already tried this i need to select range in single text box

Comment: Can i change the position of button

Comment: Did you not consider just feeding the values from these two inputs into one solitary input?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p9fgz3zw/1/

Comment: Actually i want to select these range from a single calendar not from two calendar.

Answer (score -1):

try this

[daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples)

its very simple to use

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
</script>
```